# showing the mobile menu smoothly using tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I want to show the mobile menu smoothly. Right now I'm using tailwindcss and when I click on the hamburger icon, the menu comes out instantly. I tried adding delay but it isn't doing anything. How would I make the mobile menu show smoothly when I click on the hamburger menu

```
<body>
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
        <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
          <svg class="fill-current h-8 w-8 mr-2" width="54" height="54" viewBox="0 0 54 54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.5 22.1c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05zM0 38.3c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05z"/></svg>
          <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Menu</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block lg:hidden">
          <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white" id="show-menu">
            <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto mobile-menu">
          <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
            <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4">
              Docs
            </a>
            <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4">
              Examples
            </a>
            <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white">
              Blog
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">Download</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

js

```
const btn = document.getElementById("show-menu");
const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
  menu.classList.toggle("transition")
  menu.classList.toggle("delay-150")
  menu.classList.toggle("duration-300")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution to your approach

Since you can't animate element CSS `width` or `height` when it set to `auto`. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css) on this problem.

1. Added `overflow-hidden` to your `div.mobile-menu`.
2. Add `max-h-0` as the initial height.
3. Toggle `max-h-0` and `max-h-40` to animate the menu height.

Check it out at this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-menu-height-with-vanilla-javascript-tailwindcss-extbyh)

#### Morden approachs for animating DOM element size

Calculate & save the element default (auto) width or height using:

1. Use [ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).
2. Use [getBoudingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Remember to set `overflow: hidden;` to clip their content.
Then, you can animate them by:

1. Use Javascript to set their width or height value between the default value and 0.
2. Set [CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to element that will be animated. Toggle their width or height between the default value and 0.

Comment: all the links in desktop are invisible in the codesandbox

Comment: @henrydoe simple fix by adding `lg:!max-h-none lg:!overflow-hidden` for desktop breakpoint, it will show the menu. I updated the Codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
.mobile-menu {
  transition-property: max-height;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-menu.transition-all {
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
```

```
const btn = document.getElementById("show-menu");
const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
  menu.classList.toggle("transition-all");
  menu.classList.toggle("duration-300");
});
```